# Filtering top 10 elements in pivot table does not show expected rows

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I am using the excel's pivot table to sort and filter data from Super Store Dataset from [tableau](https://community.tableau.com/docs/DOC-1236) . Here is a screen shot of my output.

[image]

The steps that I followed are:

```
a. Put Order Date in the Rows. 
b. Put Sub-Category in the Columns.
c. Put the Profit in the Sum of Values.
```

[image: Data Placement]

After that I took these steps:

```
d. Sort the Grand Total of the Sub Category from largest to smallest.
e. Sort the Grand Total of Order Date from largest to smallest.
f. Filter Top 3 from the Sub-Category.
g. Filter Top 10 from the Order Date.
```

And the above image of an excel sheet shows my output.

**Now the problem is , even though the excel sheet was supposed to show me the `top 10` orders , it only manages to show 7 to 8 orders. The rest 2 to 3 of them are either blank or should not even belong to the `top 10` category.**

[image]

Does anybody knows why is this happening. And how can this be prevented. 
Thanks.

Edit: This is how the top 15 looks like : 
I believe top 10 is based on the vertical Grand Total and it should also be a subset of the top 15.

[image]

And this is the top 20 :

[image]

Comment: Why do you think the 3 rows you've circled should not be included?

Comment: I have checked the original list and these 3 rows are way below the top 10.

Comment: No, those rows are definitely IN the top 10. You've just filtered the columns you're viewing...

Comment: Well, I looked into the top 15. It suffers from the same flaw. Shouldn't top 10 be a subset of the top 15 - up till the 10th row.

Comment: What business question are you actually trying to answer? As constructed right now, it shows your three most profitable sub-categories on your 10 most profitable days...

Comment: I want to find the 10 most profitable days for copiers, phones and accessories. Currently I think excel is not giving me 10 most profitable days, it is giving me 5 to 6 profitable days and the rest are noise.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172746/discussion-between-olly-and-motiur).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is caused by opening the .xls workbook in Compatibility Mode. This means that Version 10 pivot tables are created, which have different filtering functionality to the later, Version 12 Pivot Tables.

Change the workbook to an upgraded file format (.xlsx), and refresh your pivot tables - you'll get an interesting message informing you of the changes made to Top 10 filtering, and then the multiple Top N filters will apply correctly:

[image: Pivot filter message]

Here's some [more information about Pivot Table versions / compatibility, from Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blog/2006/08/30/pivottable-compatibility/)